# Using "gunman" to describe a fifteen year old

Tags: word-choice

Can someone who is fifteen years old, and therefore not an adult, be described as a gunman?

Comment: As easily as he might be called a batsman in cricket. If it looks like a duck, walks like a duck, and quacks like a duck . . .

Comment: If the fifteen year old was the one behind the gun, then yes.

Comment: I would say it depends on the type of crime committed. If the teenager who pulled the trigger caused the accidental death of someone or carelessly shot an innocent civilian without killing him or her, I don't think *gunman* would be appropriate. Gunman to me suggests a person who has killed deliberately or attempted to murder one or more people.

Comment: A gunman is anyone who fires a gun and is old enough to have the conscious knowledge of what it means to shoot a firearm.  We wouldn't call a three-year old baby a gunman, although three-year old babies do shoot people in the US: http://www.cnn.com/2015/02/01/us/new-mexico-toddler-shoots-parents/

Comment: In the United States, where we have frequent occasion to refer to such young people, the more common wording in newspaper accounts of gun violence involving a fifteen-year-old perpetrator is "armed youth," "gun-wielding minor," "teenage shooter," or the like. But "15-year-old gunman" wouldn't raise many eyebrows, I suspect.

Comment: I agree with @Mari-LouA in that _gunman_ implies an intent to kill or wound with the gun.  Such intent is clearly possible at 15 years old.

Comment: Note, too, that in the United States alleged gunmen as young as fourteen are sometimes "tried as adults"—that is, have their cases adjudicated through the criminal justice system for adults—rather than being processed through the juvenile justice system, depending on the nature and details of the crime and the individual's history of previous brushes with the law. So a fifteen-year-old may (on rare occasions) be not only a "gunman," but an "adult" for criminal law purposes. See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_as_an_adult).

Comment: @SvenYargs to point out the absurdity this can lead to (in a non-gun-related situation): There was a case recently in which the accused was tried as an adult for an offence of which they were also the victim.  The offence was taking indecent photos of *a minor*.  Thus the same person was  simultaneously adult and minor.

Comment: Net-net:  In the US it would be more common to describe him as "the armed teenager" or "the perpetrator" or some such, but "gunman" would likely be accepted without too many complaints.  But age 15 is around the cutoff point for this -- the term would be much less appropriate for a 13-year-old, with 14 being questionable.  And I've never seen/heard "gunman" or anything similar applied to a woman, leading one to suspect that the word is rather sexist.

Comment: @HotLicks [The link](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/51426/manhunt-for-three-gunmen-vs-womanhunt-for-three-gunwomen) says *gunman* is 600 times more common than *gunwoman*. Some news media use *female gunman* which is quite interesting. I don't recall any female gunman involved in massive U.S. shootings. Maybe, that's why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm guessing that the question turns on the occurrence of "*man*" in "*gunman*".

And yes, it is perhaps unfortunate, for considerations of gender and age, but "*gunman*" is commonly used, including for teenage boys.

Whether it would be used for a woman, teenage girl, or younger child is questionable. It probably could be, by some people, but I doubt that it typically would be.

Comment: Superman vs Superwoman, Gunman vs Gunwoman.

Comment: "Man" means "human" in this context (as it used to in every context before the PC brigade stepped up to the plate!)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If that were true there would be no question as to whether it would be used to refer to a woman.

Comment: @Random832: I'm more concerned with the etymology and dictionary definition of the word, than how the uneducated, unwashed masses have begun to wilfully misinterpret it!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's just an interesting attitude to see since I'd assumed everyone here was a descriptivist. And anyway it's really not fair to conflate objections in terms of "what sounds weird" with PC.

Comment: @Random832: Well, you know what assuming does :) Descriptivism works best when applied to a population of intelligent, educated and literate individuals, which can hardly be said for most Western cultures nowadays. From what I've seen of late, if we let descriptivism alone drive our lingual evolution, we'd only be grunting at each other in no time.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Including the most recent Oregon massacre (he is definitely called a "gunman" in news media), I don't recall any incident involving a gunman who was a female in a mass shooting in the U.S. Do you?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Dictionary definitions are snapshots into the very uneducated, unwashed masses you show disdain towards; unlike French, English does not have a standard to define it, so any definitions are necessarily fluid.

Comment: @Rathony: Since when is the English language defined only by the United States of America? There's a whole world out here, bub! And just because US shootings are mostly perpetrated by men doesn't change the fact that they are also human, or change the fact that "gunman" means "human with a gun", not "male with a gun". =)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't recall such a massacre in Oregon/Columbine/Georgia Tech, and what not happened in the U.K. That's what I meant. Why do you think *chairwoman/anchorwoman/camerawoman/sportswoman* have been born while *gunwoman* is rarely used?

Comment: @Rathony: Oh, a combination of "gunman" being corrupted to mean "male with a gun" (see my comments above where we already discussed this) and there not being many women gun murderers in the wider English-speaking world.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit All the media are calling the guy who killed 10 people in Oregon *a "gunman"*. Do you have any objection to it?

Comment: @Rathony: Nope, I don't! The individual involved, gender notwithstanding, was indeed a human being as far as I am aware.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit He is fortunately dead now. He is not a human any more.

Comment: @Rathony: I did deliberately say "was"!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I did deliberately use *is*.

Answer (score 3):

American Heritage Dictionary defines ["gunman"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gunman) as follows;

> 1. A man armed with a gun, especially an armed criminal or a professional killer.
> 2. A man skilled in the use of a gun.

It is debatable how you define "skillfulness" of a 15-year-old boy in terms of handling a firearm, but I would not use a "gunman" to describe him. I would rather use "**[armed](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/armed) teenager**".

Armed means in Merriam-Webster;

> *furnished with weapons ; also:  using or involving a
>   weapon*

Comment: In Montana, the legal minumum for a long gun (rifle) is 14. So he could have had a year of practice and may well have started much younger ...

Comment: @DavidPostill That's why I mentioned it is debatable. BTW, I don't think a 15-year old boy can be better trained for 1 year than any ex-seal or ex-marine. That's my point.

Answer (score -1):

Provided the bullets fired by the 15 year old kill as efficiently as the bullets fired by an adult, the term applies.  If the bullets are made of foam or plastic, or otherwise do no harm when impacting a body, then the term should not apply.

Comment: By this reasoning a chimpanzee with a gun would be a 'gunman'. Also, shouldn't the criteria for a 'gunman' be the possession of a gun (a real firearm, not a realistic-looking squirt gun or starter pistol), rather than the nature or harmfulness of the bullets?